# Compilation error: missing variable defined in header

Tags: android, c, build, android-ndk

I've got a header file with:

```
#ifndef DEBUG_LEVEL
#define DEBUG_LEVEL    1
#endif
```

and in my .c file I have:

```
int dbg_check_level(int level){
    return level <= DEBUG_LEVEL;
}
```

This isn't my code, but it looks fine. Of course, the header is included, but still I get this error when doing ndk-build:

```
error: expected expression before ';' token
  return level <= DEBUG_LEVEL;
```

My Android.mk file has:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c99
```

added if that makes any difference, but it was required because I have the loops containing initialization of variables all over the place.

Any suggestions as to why this won't build?

Thanks
Krystian

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [obviously `DEBUG_LEVEL` is defined empty](http://ideone.com/WrOGOS)

Comment: There is not sufficient information for an answer, but the typical reason would be that either `#define DEBUG_LEVEL 1` is excluded due to some other include guard or it is un-/redefined somewhere.

Comment: Did you forget to include that header file?

Comment: Dammit, you were right [of course]. The variable was defined at one of the Android.mk files and was carried over and over. Unfortunately, I didn't pass that to ndk-build so it was defined empty similarly to what @Selvin prepared. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Never _define_ variables in a header!

Comment: @Selvin care to add an answer? I would mark it as valid and carry on.